# Get a reference to a View that was touched during a Gesture

Tags: android, gesture

I am working on a project, in which in one of the Activities when a user issues a fling gesture I need to get a reference to the View object he touched when he first began the gesture. I've been looking all over Google for a Solution but it seems that no one have ever encountered this problem before or I am not formulating my search query properly. In either case I really need your help guys, if this is a simple problem please take in consideration that I am new to Android Development. Thanks.

Comment: what have you done so far?

Comment: Well I created a GestureDetector and passed it SimpleOnGestureListener object on which I tried to implement the onFling() method. I tried to use the location of the touch event to get a reference to the object touched but it didn't work unfortunately

Comment: then iterate over all of the child Views and check which one contains initial point

Comment: That's exactly what I did, but either I am not getting the correct coordinates or the coords on the MotionEvent don't correlate with those of the View object I am interested in.

Comment: code, code, code not words, words, words

Comment: Ok here is the implementation of onFling()
<code>public boolean onFling(MotionEvent event1, MotionEvent event2,
   float velocityX, float velocityY) {

  int[] location = new int[2];
  int xLoc, yLoc;
  for(int idx = 0; idx < numBubbles; idx++) {
  View bubble = mFrame.getChildAt(idx);
  bubble.getLocationOnScreen(location);
  xLoc = (int) event1.getX();
  yLoc = (int) event1.getY();
  if (xLoc == location[0] && yLoc == location[1]) {
        ((BubbleView) bubble).deflect(velocityX, velocityY);
         break;
     }
  }
  return true;
    
 } </code>

Comment: getLocationOnScreen gives you top/left position of the child, and you check if your MotionEvent is exactly at that point and not inside the whole child

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49789/discussion-between-oussama-bouguerne-and-pskink)